# Powerbuilder Response window hangs then App closes - Any ideas?

Tags: response, powerbuilder, terminate

The app I support is active on over 1500 users computers all using windows 10.  I have one user with a similarly configured computer that is having a problem I have not seen before.  When they run the app and it attempts to open its first "Response" window, the window displays, but the entry/edit fields are protected and the cursor shows an hour glass.  After a few seconds the window disappears and the app terminates (task manager shows the app as being unresponsive at this time).

I am using Powerbuilder 2017 r3.  I realize that an upgrade might fix this, but we are not ready to do this at the moment.

I changed the window to "Main!" as a test and I do not get the problem.  There is a data window within the response window, but it does not do a retrieve. Changing the window type is not a solution I can live with.

Comment: Try a PBDEBUG trace and see if that sheds any light. (Can be done with the EXE.)